# HTML5 'contenteditable' valid values

Tags: html, contenteditable

What values can I choose for the attribute contenteditable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can contain:

- `true`
- `false`
- `inherit`

**Quoting:**

> The contentEditable  DOM attribute, on
>   getting, must return the string "**true**"
>   if the content attribute is set to the
>   true state, **false**" if the content
>   attribute is set to the false state,
>   and "**inherit**" otherwise. On setting,
>   if the new value is case-insensitively
>   equal to the string "inherit" then the
>   content attribute must be removed, if
>   the new value is case-insensitively
>   equal to the string "true" then the
>   content attribute must be set to the
>   string "true", if the new value is
>   case-insensitively equal to the string
>   "false" then the content attribute
>   must be set to the string "false", and
>   otherwise the attribute setter must
>   raise a SYNTAX_ERR exception.

**Source:** http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html

Comment: there is no inherit value

Answer (score 1):

true, false  or inherit

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable

Comment: there is no inherit value

Answer (score 0):

There is no "inherit" value. Inherit is implied by omitting the attribute. The attribute has 3 values and 3 states. Values are empty string, true and false. States are true, false and inherit.

[In there a inherit value for the contenteditable attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802581/in-there-a-inherit-value-for-the-contenteditable-attribute/18803482#comment27731228_18803482)