# HTML5 contenteditable attribute question

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 contenteditable question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116833/html5-contenteditable-question)

what is the contenteditable attributes default value?

Comment: @Yi Jiang no its not two different questions

Comment: Go back to your last question, click through the link in the accepted answer, read the first paragraph, what does it say? "In addition, there is a third state, the *inherit* state, which is the *missing value default* (and the *invalid value default*)." (Emphasis not mine)

Comment: @Yi Jiang exactly what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

My browsers show this:

- **Opera 10.63**: `inherit`
- **Google Chrome 9.0.570.1 dev**: `false`
- **Internet Explorer 8** (isContentEdible): `false`
- **Firefox 4.0 b6**: `inherit`

[This attribute can be set to](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable): `true`, `false` and `inherit`.

Comment: so in other words, as with most browsers, you have to define a sane default or expect unexpected behavior, right?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether it matters or not. If you don't want it to make the child elements editable, you have to force the children to be set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Running the Javascript code produces `inherit` on my Firefox/3.6.12.

```
alert(document.body.contentEditable);
```

Comment: huhhhhh what does that mean? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: It was a Javascript code that get the attribute 'contenteditable' from the `<body>` element. That code displays a popup with the value of it, in this case `inherit`. `inherit` means it's inherited from the parent element. It's `false` by default, otherwise it would produce funny results, being able to edit everything in a document.