# In there a inherit value for the contenteditable attribute?

Tags: html, attributes, contenteditable, inheritance

As per

[HTML-5](http://www.html-5.com/attributes/contenteditable-attribute.html)

The values are "empty string", "true" and "false". There is no "inherit" value. If the attribute is not set, than it *inherits* from the parent element. "inherit" is a state since it is a Enumerated Attribute.

[html5-contenteditable-valid-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116833/html5-contenteditable-valid-values)

What happens when you travel upwards in the DOM and find no Parent/Ancestor Element with the attribute set till the root html element?

Comment: one would say `default value` which would be `false`

Comment: @JakubMichálek: There is the "missing value default" and "invalid value default" which is the "inherit" state as in omitting the attribute!

Comment: No, I meant the default value of the browser. If there is no element to inherit from, then all elements are inheriting the browser's default value, which can be either true or false. In most cases, it would be false. But you can make a browser with true as a default I guess.

Comment: @JakubMichálek: Well the "translate" attribute "inherits" from the parent/ancestor as far as the root/html element which has a "translate-enabled" state. Can't find anything which state that it is the same with "contenteditable" although logically it should be "false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inherit state says that the element is *editable* if it's parent is.

The ultimate ancestor is the document object. The editability state of the document object is determined by the `designMode` property. The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/editing.html#making-entire-documents-editable%3a-the-designmode-idl-attribute) says " Initially, documents must have their designMode disabled."

Comment: That does not answer the main question about the inherit being a value of the attribute contenteditable. "All other values are not valid". The "inherit state" is "implied" by "omiting the contenteditable attribute".

Comment: @Jawad - That's a statement, not a question. What is it that you don't understand?